# Jest: How to I test a function that calls another function in the body

Tags: javascript, testing, random, jestjs

I am trying to test the makeRandomComputerMove function, however, I am unable to properly mock the getRandomNumber function exported from the same module using Jest.

If I call the getRandomNumber function directly in the test file it works as expected, but I was under the impression that mocking the function in the test file should force the internal makeRandomComputerMove function to use the mocked value.

Any help would be appreciated.

test.ticTacToe.js

```
describe('TicTacToe Utils', () => {
    const randomMock = jest.spyOn(Utils, 'getRandomNumber')
        .mockReturnValueOnce(0)
        .mockReturnValueOnce(1)

    const board = [
        [['X'], [], []],
        [[], [], []],
        [[], [], []]
        ]

    it('makeRandomComputerMove', () => {
        const location = Utils.makeRandomComputerMove(board)
        // expect(location.x).toBe(0)
        // expect(location.y).toBe(1)
    })
})
```

ticTacToe.js

```
export const getRandomNumber = (min, max) => {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

export const makeRandomComputerMove = (board) => {
    const location = {};
    location.x = getRandomNumber(0, board.length - 1);
    location.y = getRandomNumber(0, board.length - 1);
    if (location.x < 3 && location.y < 3) {
        return location

    }
    return makeRandomComputerMove(board);   
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to mock `getRandomNumber` while it's being called by `makeRandomComputerMove` within the same file.

Instead, you could move `getRandomNumber` to a separate file, which can then be mocked:

*getRandomNumber.js*

```
export const getRandomNumber = (min, max) => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

*ticTacToe.js*

```
import { getRandomNumber } from './getRandomNumber';

export const makeRandomComputerMove = (board) => {
  const location = {};
  location.x = getRandomNumber(0, board.length - 1);
  location.y = getRandomNumber(0, board.length - 1);
  if (location.x < 3 && location.y < 3) {
    return location
  }
  return makeRandomComputerMove(board)
}
```

*test.ticTacToe.js*

```
import Utils from './'
import { getRandomNumber } from './getRandomNumber'

jest.mock('./getRandomNumber', () => ({
  getRandomNumber: jest.fn()
}))

describe('TicTacToe Utils', () => {
  getRandomNumber.mockReturnValueOnce(0)
  getRandomNumber.mockReturnValueOnce(1)

  const board = [
    [['X'], [], []],
    [[], [], []],
    [[], [], []]
    ]

  it('makeRandomComputerMove', () => {
    const location = Utils.makeRandomComputerMove(board)
    expect(location.x).toBe(0)
    expect(location.y).toBe(1)
  })
})
```

I hope this helps.